# ActionBar Background Color Problem Andorid Studio

Tags: android

I am developing an App with Android Studio but I have not been able to solve a detail with the background color of the ActionBar: I have put a certain color to the bar, which is It looks correctly in the emulator, but when I load the app on my cell, it looks black. Can someone guide me with this?

This is my themes.xmls:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Tenis2020" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

[see the color difference between the emulator and the cell phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqIHk.jpg)

Comment: do you multiple version of style.xml for different APIs?

Comment: you are probably in dark mode. You should turn that off and try it. Check [here](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00082645/#:~:text=First%2C%20swipe%20down%20from%20the,off%2C%20tap%20the%20icon%20again.) or use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=systems.maju.darkmode&hl=en&gl=US) to turn it off and try it.

Comment: Excelent !, that was the problem (Dark Mode), Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Here are multiple versions of themes.xml. One for 'Night Mode' and another for 'Day Mode' or 'light mode'. You have changed the color of the action bar in one but not in the other. Probably your phone is in dark mode and the emulator is in light mode or day mode. That is why you have caught the difference.

You change the color of the actionbar in all versions of themes.xml.

[image: See the screenshot.]